# kaggle file path not found Issue

Tags: pandas, kaggle

I can't find this data file in Kaggle can you help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pggtP.png)

df = pd.read_csv('/Kaggle/input/sheindata/shein_sample.csv')
I expect it to read the csv file from that directory but still getting this message